# SetState() does not change my state in a PopupMenuButton

Tags: flutter, state, popupmenu

My screen bears a popup menu where the user can pass in expert mode by taping on a button (see the screen shot below).

[image]

But, though the `setState()` is being executed, the redraw always resets ìsExpertMode' to its default value (true).

```
class _SmartboxDashboard extends State<SmartboxDashboard>
    with
        Module<SmartboxDashboard>,
        SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, 
        AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<SmartboxDashboard> {

    /// Is expert mode?
    bool isExpertMode = true;

  
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: _tabSectionBodies.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(isScrollable: true, tabs: tabSectionTabs),
            title: Text(deviceDisplayName(widget.device.name)),
            actions: [
              PopupMenuButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                  position: PopupMenuPosition.under,
                  itemBuilder: (context) {
                    return [
                      
                      PopupMenuItem<int>(
                          value: 2,
                          child: ListTile(
                              leading: ElevatedButton(
                                  child: Text(isExpertMode
                                      ? "Normal mode"
                                      : "Expert mode"),
                                  //value: isExpertMode,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      isExpertMode =
                                          appState.isExpertMode = !isExpertMode;
                                    });
                                  }),
                              title: Text(
                                  isExpertMode ? "Expert mode" : "Normal mode"),
                              subtitle: Text(isExpertMode
                                  ? "Turning to \"normal mode\" will streamline the information and you only see essentials informationabout your battery"
                                  : "Turning to \"expert mode\" will show more screens and deeper information about your batteries"),
                            )
                         ),
                      
                    ];
                  },
                  onSelected: (value) async {

                    switch (value) {
                      case 2:
                        //setState(() {
                        //  isExpertMode = appState.isExpertMode = !isExpertMode;
                        //  print("Expert mode turned to $isExpertMode");
                        });
                        break;
                    }
                    setState(() {
                      sharing = false;
                    });
                  }),
            ]),
        body: TabBarView(children: _tabSectionBodies),
```

Comment: Don't we need to override the build function?

Comment: Is `bool isExpertMode = true;` inside the build method or outside? It's hard to tell as you left out the method header.

Comment: Lol, you were right! My bad, I dropped the line INSIDE the build. My component is too large, I need to refactor it. So that's the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use **StatefulBuilder**

bool isSwitched = true;

```
 PopupMenuItem(child: StatefulBuilder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                      void Function(void Function()) setState) {
                    return Switch(
                      value: isSwitched,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          isSwitched = value;
                          print(isSwitched);
                        });
                      },
                      activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                      activeColor: Colors.green,
                    );
                  },
                ))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. This makes the state updates within the PopupMenu. But when I close the menu and reopen, the state is still reset. It sounds that the state does not bubble up. Any idea?

Comment: after changing the state of the switch from the popup menu you might be saving it in a variable so it can reflect. as it is after open

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca i think its because you `setState` inside PopUpMenuItem widget tree.
the value not updated for your class `StatefullWidget`.  to make it clear try with different name  `builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter statePop ) {`  . i hope you got what i mean

Comment: updated the code as per your requirement

Comment: to update value in your `PopUpMenuItem` you can call `statePop` , and for your `StatefullWidget class` , by default use `setState`

Comment: StatefulBuilder works. The fact that the state wasn't bubbling up is my bad: due to the length of the code, I misplaced my `isExpertMode`: it was inside the `build()` hence the reset. Moving it outside fixed the issue. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be
`isExpertMode = !isExpertMode;`.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but part of the answer was to use a `StatefulBuilder` as told by @MohitJadav86

Answer (score 0):

You need to use StatefulBuilder here, because the context and setState scope has been changed. Whenever new StatefulBuilder Widget is used you will get a new setState local function to update the state.